# How do I add a call to FORTRAN code to a project in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fortran

My company has a bunch of Fortran code. Traditionally, we compiled the code we needed into a .dll and called that .dll when we needed a calculation done. We are now trying to create an iPad app, which unfortunately means we can't just call a .dll anymore.

One of my coworkers have managed to make a simple Command Line Tool project, where we call a Fortran file to write "Hello, World" in the debugger.  However, when I try to get it to work on view based iPad app, I get a bunch of linker errors saying the symbols I'm using cannot be found.  I know that the Command Line Tool uses a .cpp file to actually run the Fortran, and I've seen many threads concerning calling .cpp files in an app, but all the ones I've seen are outdated, directly contradict each other, and their fixes don't work for me.

My question is, **is there a more direct way to call Fortran straight from a .m file?**  If not, **what do I have to do to take the working Command Line Tool and get it into an app?**

UPDATE 1: following the tutorials posted in the comments, I have been able to create a .o file from my Fortran code.  I can do a File-Add Files to add it in easily enough, but now how do I actually call it?

UPDATE 2: Okay, baby steps.  I found out you can make a .a static library (I'll call it "new_library") from .o files ("source_file.o") using the Terminal command `ar crv new_library.a source_file.o` (you can do it for multiple .o files by just adding `source_file2.o source_file3.o` for as many .o files as you want - NOTE: make sure you use `cd` to get to the folder where the .o files are located).  I'm pretty sure Xcode will work with .a files, but it seems a .h file is still needed to let the other files in the project (like the view controllers) make calls to what's in the .a file. I know I can make a new .a file from Xcode itself (New Project -> iOS -> Framework & Library -> Cocoa Touch Static Library), but when I've done it that way in the past, I just write normal .m and .h files, and when I build the new library it just mashes all the .m files into 1 .a.  When I want to use the code in that .a in another project, I just import the .a and all the .h files into the new project, and I can call the methods in the .a file just as if I had imported all the separate .m files.  So the next question is, **do I still need a .h when my .a is made with the terminal instead of Xcode?**  If so, **how would I make a Fortran header file?**  If not, **how do I call my Fortran code in the .a?**

Comment: There are several questions about Fortran and iOS on SO.  They all seem to point to using a Fortran to C translator.  At that point you can use XCode to compile and link the result.

Comment: Do you know of any Fortran to C translator for code younger than 20 years? I do not.

Comment: @PeterM: As I said in my OP, I have been able to find a lot of old posts on suggestions on how to do this, but none of them work for me.  Is there a specific one you have used and has worked for you?

Comment: @GeneralMike It wasn't clear to me in your question that you had used a translator.  Sorry about that.  But if I did have anything that worked for me I would have posted an answer instead of a comment.  My point was meant to be that you are in the same boat as a bunch of other people.  Which is surprising given that LLVM supports Fortran (well via a different front end than Clang).

Comment: You can use the `ISO_C_BINDING` mechanism of Fortran to make the code callable from C (and hence from Objective-C). There are two things to consider though: 1) Apple does not provide a Fortran compiler in their LLVM suite (get one from http://hpc.sourceforge.net); 2) you need a Fortran compiler capable of cross-compiling to ARM code objects (with the apropriate ABI) in order to build executable that would run on the device.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I actually already downloaded and installed the compiler you linked.  Is it capable of the things you mentioned in part 2, or will I need to find something additional?  I'm actually not very experienced, so I'll have to do some research into pretty much all of the things you mentioned.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: No, the compiler from the Mac HPC site is only capable of producing x86 code, both 32- and 64-bit. You'd have to search the Internet for ARM-capable Fortran compiler, e.g. the [DragonEgg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/) project. You can also build a cross compiler from sources yourself. You can find many guides on how to build the GCC toolchain on Mac OS on the Internet.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like building my own compiler would be miles over my head, so I guess I'll check out DragonEgg.  Thanks for the link once again.

Comment: It's not rocket science building a compiler. Here is a step by step guide on how to build the latest GCC on Mac OS X - [link](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/07/21/compiling-gcc-4-7-1-mac-osx-lion/).

Comment: @HristoIliev Will it fork for iOS and not only for MacOS?

Comment: @VladimirF, I have to check that. ARM is in the list of the supported architectures. Mach-O object format too.

Comment: @HristoIliev: so since ARM and Mach-O are both supported, does that mean this will work for iOS then?  Sorry to have to bother you so much on this, but as I said, this is all a bit out of the realm I usually work in.

Comment: @GeneralMike, an executable file is produced by linking many object files. If GCC can be configured as a cross-compiler, able to produce compatible ARM objects, then you can link your Fortran code together with the Objective-C code to produce a working executable. Unfortunately I am not an iOS developer and cannot provide you with concrete instructions on how to do it. Search the net - there are enthusiasts who develop for iOS on non-OSX platforms and they usually provide guides on building GCC as a cross-compiler.

Comment: Okay, that explains a lot.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VladimirF can you find any fortran cold using something newer than 20 years? :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to sum up things:

1. You need a FORTRAN cross compiler that can produce ARM code. GCC is probably a good choice. But you will need to build it yourself from the source downloads.
2. Compile your FORTRAN code and put it into a static library. This task is perform outside XCode, probably from the command line.
3. Write C header files for those FORTRAN routines that you wand to call directly from C. You might want to look at [Fortran and C/C++ mixed programming](http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/comp/docs/notes/not017.html) or [Tutorial: Using C/C++ and Fortran together](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html). These pages explain how to map the C data types to FORTRAN data types and vice versa.
4. Add the C header files and the static library to the XCode project.
5. Import the C header files into your Objective-C files (.m) where required and call the FORTRAN routines as if they were C functions.
6. Build the iOS app with XCode.

Comment: Okay, so this is indeed the steps to take to get this to work.  I think right now I'm getting hung up on the 3rd step - I'm getting some Linker errors, but hopefully the links you provided will help. Unfortunately, I've been temporarly shifted to another project, so I might not get a chance to work on this more for a couple weeks.  If I can get it working once I get back to it, I'll be sure to accept.